# Duplicity with Google Cloud throwing TypeError

Tags: duplicity

I had been using duplicity successfully to backup to GCS for some time but a few months ago it stopped working. I believe there's an encoding problem with moving to Python 3. I have seen a few similar problems floating around (e.g., https://bugs.launchpad.net/duplicity/+bug/1843995) which claim that similar bugs are resolved, but I'm still getting the following:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 106, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 92, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1525, in main
    action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 1175, in ProcessCommandLine
    globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 225, in get_backend
    obj = get_backend_object(url_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 211, in get_backend_object
    return factory(pu)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 173, in __init__
    self.resetConnection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 198, in resetConnection
    self.bucket = self.conn.create_bucket(self.bucket_name,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/boto/gs/connection.py", line 93, in create_bucket
    response = self.make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 659, in make_request
    auth_path = self.calling_format.build_auth_path(bucket, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 94, in build_auth_path
    path = '/' + bucket
 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your probably not using the latest https://launchpad.net/duplicity/+milestone/0.8.14 .

lots of encoding errors have been fixed since the port to python3.

in case you are backing up to S3 there is also the new boto3+s3:// based on the maintained boto3 module.

here the install notes from the release announcement (take care to remove the distro's duplicity as suggested in the bottom first)

> There are multiple options both stable and daily:
>
> - Source - https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity
> - Stable tarball install - https://launchpad.net/duplicity/+download
> - Daily duplicity PPA - [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git)
> - Stable duplicity PPA - [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-release-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-release-git) [https://code.launchpad.net/~duplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eduplicity-team/+archive/ubuntu/duplicity-develop-git)
> - Stable snap builds - “sudo snap install duplicity —classic"
> - Latest snap builds - “sudo snap install duplicity —classic —edge"
> - Latest pip3 builds - “sudo pip3 install duplicity"
>
> NOTE: UNinstall duplicity first if it was installed via the distribution repository.  For Ubuntu, that would be "sudo apt-get purge duplicity".

..ede/duply.net

Comment: None work seemingly, this bug is still present as of mid 2021

Answer (score 0):

my way:

0. `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 venv/`
1. `source venv/bin/activate`
2. `git clone git@github.com:boto/boto.git -b develop`
3. In boto/utils.py:871 Patch the line to `value = str(value.encode('utf-8'))`
4. from boto/ `python setup.py install`
5. `git clone https://github.com/henrysher/duplicity`
6. `cd duplicity` && `python setup.py install`